# What filter should I use for non gaussian distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, gaussian-process, particle-filter

I have a process that measureing distance between 10-100mm and I currently measuring at 11-18mm with a fixed distance. I want to improve this measurement by adding a filter.

Here is the distribution of the complete measurement. Take account that this is a non gaussian distrbution because the average changes over time.
[image]

Here is the average and deviation that changes over time. In this case, I have taken 50 measurements and then compute the average and deviation of it, then next 50 measurements and repeated the process.

The smaller number I use to compute the average, the more nosy it becomes. Larger number gives better measurement results, but slower measurement.

**Question:**

What type of filter should I use for a measurement that has a non gaussian distribution?
In this case, the average changes over time.

Should I use a particle filter? I have read about it, but I did not understand how I should estimate the distribution by just having 10 measurements samples.

[image][image]

The raw values are integer values between 10-18mm.

[image]

[image]

**To reproduce this example**

Download **VL6180X_Distribution.m** and **log.txt** from here. Run the .m file with MATLAB or GNU Octave. Then you have the plots.

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/STM32-Libraries/tree/master/VL6180X/Distribution

Comment: Could you explain what exactly a "filter" is in this context?

Comment: @mhdadk Thank you for your reply. Yes I can. My goal is to make the average more smooth over time. As you can see above, the mean is very bouncy. I don't like that.